# AWS CodeDeploy Triggers running custom script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I believe AWS CodeDeploy Triggers only supports SNS notifications (currently). Is it possible to hook into the events, i.e. DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE, to run a custom bash/batch/ps script?

Motivation is to provide slack notifications of success/failure in one of our dev channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific use case you should use a Lambda function. Amazon [provides blueprints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-slack-integration-blueprints-for-aws-lambda/) for Lambda functions that post to Slack, and you can subscribe Lambda functions to an SNS topic.

Comment: Thanks for help, terraformed the sns topic, subscription, deployment group triggers and lambda function: https://gist.github.com/lukehutton/74c47f7fd0dfdf08cc26d6e3403fd61a